# Determine whether a user came from an email, and if so which client

Tags: email, ssl, https, referrer

Before I get a spam of comments saying this shouldn't be done, I'm using it as a 'nice to have' with plenty of ux thought going into getting them to the right page if I sniff the referrer incorrectly.

Anyway, I have the following questions:

### Can you sniff via https (gmail mainly). Are you able to get a referrer off an https domain if you, yourself also have an ssl?

### Do local clients, such as outlook 2013 and thunderbird, give off a referrer when a user clicks the link?

-Led

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. Web clients (like gmail.com, etc) are all done over HTTPS, which doesn't send a referrer. Dedicated clients don't give a referrer either, as they just tell your web browser to open a new tab or window with a specific address.